# Configuracion de nodejs en cyberpanel

Tags: nodejs, vps, proxy

He configurado un VPS con centOs y cyberpanel. Anteriormente siguiendo las instrucciones de este enlace https://cyberpanel.co/configurar-la-aplicacion-express-js-en-cyberpanel-openlitespeed-2/ configure un api node directamente en una ruta sin puertos ni proxy inverso. Pero el dominio cyberpanel.co no esta en funcionamiento y no logro configurar un nuevo api node en otro subdominio diferente.
He intentado con proxy inverso pero al parecer no lo logro. Tambien he intentado con pm2 pero no muestra nada al ingresar a la ruta. Cuando intento acceder a subdominio queda cargando y nunca ingresa. Alguien sabe de algun tutorial o documentacion que pueda leer?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Quisiera saber como debo configurar cyberpanel o OpenLiteSpeed para poder usar un api creada con nodejs. Yo he modificado mi context para enviar las peticiones a un archivo server.js pero no ha funcionado. lo hago de esta manera. context / {
  type                    appserver
  location                $VH_ROOT/public_html/
  binPath                 /usr/bin/node
  appType                 node
  startupFile             server.js
  appserverEnv            1
  maxConns                100

  accessControl  {
    allow                 *
  }
}

Comment: solo conectate por ssh e instalas node, despues ya podras poner a correr tu proyecto en cyberpanel,  sudo yum install nodejs